# EntityFramework and sql views

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, view

I am wondering if EF6 does track changes for views. Say I have a view that is based on multiple joins in my database. When I update or insert a record in some table, it affect the view, does EF track this change and notify it ?.

thank you in advance for your valuable help.

**Info:** I am using EF6 with .net 4.5.1 in VS Community 2015. the database is an SQLite Database.

Comment: Why don't you just try? I think this may differ among database providers. And code-first vs database-first matters.

Comment: I am using code-first from database. My database is empty and have many tables (20) I don't have data to test.